# How to design numberpad in view in iOS?

Tags: ios

[image]

I am new to iOS designing.

I want to design number pad like above design in view controller using storyboard.

Any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The default iOS number keyboard looks the same. Just use this code:

```
myTextfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
```

Please let me know if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a completely custom control, you should simply add UIButtons or UIImageViews to your viewControllers view and add appropriate target/action or IBActions.

Answer (score 0):

with the help of 12 UIButton and 12 same size image, we can create this custom numpad in UIView.